# Emulating a Procreate Brush Pen in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush, pen-tool, lettering, calligraphy

I'm a hand letterer looking to take my work to Illustrator and I was wondering if there's a way to emulate [this sort of look & method](https://www.instagram.com/p/BXcWG1DDDfQ/?taken-by=devandvan) in Illustrator.

So far I've only been toying with a Wacom tablet and calligraphic brushes but the smoothing still needs some getting used to.

I'm fairly new to Illustrator so I was wondering if there was a 'snapping' and 'curving' kinda mechanic like in the above linked Instagram video.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that "curving" isn't just created by the movement of the pen on the screen? Could be just a bad filming angle. Unless I misunderstood what you mean by that.

Comment: Adobe Draw on the iPad tends to be better at this sort of thing. And that would be a closer emulation to using ProCreate on a tablet.

Comment: Have you tried changing the smoothing and fidelity options in the brush tool?

Comment: The "curving" motion you see in the video, when the stroke align itself to become more clean is called StreamLine and it's a Procreate feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to play with caligraphic brush angle and roundness.
That curves are a delay of video.
Here is an exeample:

[image]

Comment: Yup been doing this so far. Seems like this is the closest thing in Illustrator so far. Thanks for the overview!